# How to deploy MVC web app on IIS Express?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-express

I have developed an MVC 4 web app on one machine. Debugging works fine on this machine in VS 2012 (which I believe it deploys it locally to IIS Express).

I would like to deploy/publish it to another machine with IIS Express 7.5.
Currently, I am copying the whole project folder to the target machine and configure applicationhost.config manually to have it run the web app.

Is this a proper way to deploy the web app?
Do I actually need to copy the whole project folder?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If in `Visual Studio`, right click on the project, then `Publish`.

Comment: Thank you ! I don't know how to upvote your comment, but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to publish the application to a IIS web server.

In `Visual Studio`, right click on the project, then click `Publish`.

Check out this `MSDN` article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698(v=vs.110).aspx